Connection ID required when deploying blazor server in different folder
I'm trying to publish / deploy a blazor interactive server application using an Apache server that is serving in different folders.
So, I'm trying to move the application to a specific folder.
For this, I'm following these instructions Host and deploy ASP.NET Core Blazor.
But when I run the application I get the error Connection ID required. The URL open is correct (http://localhost:5401/email2db) where email2db is the path where I want the application.
I have googled, and I see different alternatives, and I'm testing (allow CORS, specific routing mapping, ...) but I want to imagine that is very more simple than this.
What I have done until now:

I have modified the App.razor file adding the <base>tag

@inject WebOptions webOptions 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
...
    <!-- base href="/email2db/" /-->
    <base href="/@(webOptions.PathBase)" />

NOTICE: Here I'm using an injected configuration, but I have also tested with hardcoded value

I have modified the program.cs adding the MapBlazorHub

        app.MapBlazorHub(webConfiguration.GetValue<String>("PathBase")!);

NOTICE: Again, here I use a configuration, but also tested hard coded

I have modified the Properties/launchSettings.json

    "profiles": {
      "http": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "dotnetRunMessages": true,
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5104",
        "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5104/email2db/",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
      },
...

Any suggestion/guide will be welcome. Have I to continue with CORS? Or with Map(...
And another annoying tip. With this configuration, the server try to serve the pages from both paths http://localhost:5104/pages/mypage and http://localhost:5104/email2db/pages/mypage

Finally, I got my goal (to deploy in a subfolder).
I think I have found 2 different bugs:

NavigateTo does not honor the PathBase set in program with app.UsePathBase("/myvirtualfolder/");. It knows it (if you debug you can see the attribute) but does not apply it when ask for navigation, neither absolute or relative. I have found other comments here and it appears in Net8.0 first time.

The doc indicates you have to use either option <base> tag or app.UsePathBase. This is incorrect: YOU HAVE TO USE BOTH!.


In short

Add app.UsePathBase("/myvirtualfolder/"); just below WebApplication app = builder.Build(); in program.cs. It's mandatory to be the first line. With this, the communication with server works (dissapears the "Content ID" error)
Add <base href="/myvirtualfolder/" />in App.razor
Change all NavigateTo or href to relative. So the base tag will be applied. E.g.


NavigateTo("/myotherpage/{var}") to NavigateTo("myotherpage/{var}")
href="/myapi/resource" to href="myapi/resource"


Change your Properties/launchSetting.json to use new path

    "profiles": {
      "http": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "commandLineArgs": "--pathbase=/myvirtualfolder",
        "dotnetRunMessages": true,
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5104",
        "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5104/myvirtualfolder/",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }

NOTE: The app.MapBlazorHub("/myvirtualfolder/); is not needed here. This is only needed if you deploy an additional SignarR hub (not my case)
NOTE2: It's important to understand that UsePathBase does not ADD a PathBase. In fact, it REMOVES from the url path before passing to the route. I mean, the call to http://example.com/myvirtualfolder/page/mypageis converted to http://example.com/page/mypage. This is important because the server will serve the page from BOTH urls (with and without base path). This can have some security collateral issues. I'm solving it using a reverse proxy in front.

Thanks for thorough answer & correction to docs
